# How far does the cursor move when you hit the arrow key?

Tags: cursor, standards, measurement

How far does the cursor move when you hit the arrow key?  I am assuming it is a standardized movement in millimetres.  Obviously it is dependent on the font size when a larger size is used, but I work with graphics and in most software, you can nudge your images in a direction. I was wondering if that is a standard amount.  Is is the same in say Windows, Adobe, Inkscape, Gimp, Silhouette Studio, or any of the other graphics programs?

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard. It depends on the program and how it implements it. With text it is often one character, but with variable with characters, the cursor can obviously move different pixels depending on the width of the character, and if it reaches the end of text, it will not move at all, whereas in other editors it may freely move into non occupied space.

So the short answer is: various, because it really depends on the implementation by that specific program and by what action you are performing at that time.